# C++ declaration is incompatible

Tags: c++

These are the code files for my swapchain, I am using dx11 BTW, so you guys dont get lost on why I'm using d3d device, etc.

```cpp
//Header
#pragma once
class SwapChain
{
public:
    SwapChain();
    bool init(HWND hwnd, UINT width, UINT height);
    bool release();
    ~SwapChain();
private:
    IDXGISwapChain* m_swap_chain;
};
```

```cpp
//cpp
#include "SwapChain.h"
#include "GraphicsEngine.h"

SwapChain::SwapChain()
{
}

bool SwapChain::init(HWND hwnd, UINT width, UINT height)
{
    ID3D11Device*device= GraphicsEngine::get()->m_d3d_device;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
    desc.BufferCount = 1;
    desc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    desc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    desc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Windowed = TRUE;




    HRESULT hr=GraphicsEngine::get()->m_dxgi_factory->CreateSwapChain(device, &desc, &m_swap_chain);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}



bool SwapChain::release()
{
    return true;
}

SwapChain::~SwapChain()
{
}
```

I am trying to make a swapchain for my graphics engine, and I have the same params as in the header file. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error?

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
> Error
> (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "bool SwapChain::init( hwnd,  width,  height)" (declared at line 6 of "C:\Users\sudo\source\repos\DX 3D\DX 3D\SwapChain.h")    DX 3D   C:\Users\sudo\source\repos\DX 3D\DX 3D  C:\Users\sudo\source\repos\DX 3D\DX 3D\SwapChain.cpp    8

I am new to C++, by the way.

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message.

Comment: If this is Visual Studio the Output Tab has the error messages in a better format for copying text.

Comment: `SwapChain.h` is missing `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <dxgi.h>` (perhaps indirectly via `GraphicsEngine.h`?), so types like `HWND`, `UINT` and `IDXGISwapChain` are unknown to the compiler when the `SwapChain` class is declared.

Comment: @RemyLebeau They are all included in ```GraphicsEngine.h```

Comment: @xd-sudo then your `#include "GraphicsEngine.h"` statement is in the wrong place, it needs to be moved into `SwapChain.h` above the declaration of the `SwapChain` class.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly invoke `ZeroMemory` on `desc`. You can declare it as `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc = {};` to have the same effect.